# jQuery slick slider behaving weird

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am using Slick Slider for my product loop so the products can be a slider.
But on the page load there is a big white gap below the products, when i grab the products en start sliding the height is getting normal. Does any one know why it behaves like this?

Javascript:

```
$('.product-loop-home').slick({
      dots: false,
      infinite: false,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 8000,
      pauseOnFocus: false,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
});
```

Website URL: https://www.dev.ruitershopboxmeer.nl/

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you =>

```
div.slick-track{
   height: 500px !important; // height you want 500 is super
}
```

happy coding